# neo4j start causes ERROR: JAVA_HOME is incorrectly defined as

Tags: java, environment-variables, neo4j

I'm trying to run the neo4j server on an Ubuntu machine using this command:

```
sudo neo4j start
```

But it gives me this error:

```
ERROR: JAVA_HOME is incorrectly defined as /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64/bin/ (the executable /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64/bin//bin/java does not exist)
```

Now, I have set JAVA_HOME to the correct directory where Java is installed. Here is what I get when I run `echo $JAVA_HOME`:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
```

I don't know where it's getting that value for JAVA_HOME. I checked the configuration files but I couldn't find any variables referring to JAVA_HOME that I might need to set.

Comment: I got the same error when I installed Neo4j on fedora using `yum` , to solve the issue I removed Neo4j installed usig yum and downloaded the [tar file](https://neo4j.com/download-center/#releases) (under `Community Server` -> `Neo4j Community Edition x.x.x` -> `Linux/Mac`) and started the server without problem.